# PHP modulus function Issue

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create some HTML using php/mysql.

My HTML should be something like below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>  
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>  
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
</div>
..........
<div class="row">
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>  
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
</div>
```

There are 4 content divs in each row.

This is how I tried it in my PHP while loop, but its not work for me.

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {    

  if($i % 4 == 0) {
    $html  = "<div class='row'>\n";
  }

  $html .= "    <div class='checkbox col-sm-3'>\n"; 
  $html .= "       <label>\n"; 
  $html .= "         <input class='custom' name='facility[$fid]' type='checkbox'>\n"; 
  $html .= "         <span class='lbl'> {$fname}</span>\n"; 
  $html .= "       </label>\n";   
  $html .= "    </div>\n";   

  if($i++ % 4 == 4) { 
    $html .= "  </div>\n";
  } 

  $ckbxOurPut[] = $html;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what it the wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by this if($i++ % 4 == 4)  ?. When this satisfy

Comment: what do you mean with  "but its not work for me" ?   . you have error .. wrong result ? .. no result .. ?.

Comment: @scaisEdge. It has a wrong result. It is not printing closing tag for `.row` div.

Comment: what is `$ckbxOurPut` and why it is inside loop ?

Comment: its is an array. Because I need to get the output into an array..

Comment: this is causing the problem, you should write this outside loop

Comment: you have an other problem on line 4 of your code : you use `$html  = "<div class='row'>\n";` instead of `$html  .= "<div class='row'>\n";`

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅. Yes I was the issue. problem solved. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to change `if($i++ % 4 == 4)` to `if($i++ % 4 == 3)`

Also, on line 4 of your code, you use `$html = "<div class='row'>\n";` instead of `$html .= "<div class='row'>\n";`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($i++ % 4 == 4) {
```

$var % 4 can never be 4. What you want is this:

```
 if($i++ % 4 == 3) {
```

Edit: also in line 4 you redefine $html, when you should just concatenate (.= operator)

Comment: @user3733831 yet, this answer is correct, i just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ this was definitely an issue, but may be `$ckbxOurPut[] = $html;` is another problem

Answer (score 1):

Make this changes
1. Modulus changes 2. Push html in array after outer div close.

```
 if($i++ % 4 == 3) { 
   $html .= "  </div>\n";
   $ckbxOurPut[] = $html;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13
];

$i = 0;
$html = "";
foreach($a as $val)
{



   if($i % 4 == 0) {
     $html  .= "<div class='row'>\n";
   }

  $html .= $val."\n";          

   if($i++ % 4 == 3) { 
     $html .= "  </div>\n";
   } 

} 

 if($i % 4 != 3) { 
     $html .= "  </div>\n";
 } 


echo $html;
```

Comment: anything modulus 4 will never give 4 so the div will never be closed

Comment: of course, I forgot change condition to:  if($i % 4 == 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
$html  = "<div class='row'>";

while($stmt->fetch()) {

    $i++;
    if($i == 5) {
         $html  .= "</div><div class='row'>";
         $i = 1;
     }

     $html .= "    <div class='checkbox col-sm-3'>\n";
     $html .= "       <label>\n";
     $html .= "         <input class='custom' name='facility[$fid]' type='checkbox'>\n";
     $html .= "         <span class='lbl'> {$fname}</span>\n";
     $html .= "       </label>\n";
     $html .= "    </div>\n";


}

$html  .= "</div>";
echo $html;
```